# How can I hide the button if the one that logs in has Admin Role?

Tags: angular

If a simple user logs in the button does show up, but if a user with Admin Role logs in it does show up and i don't want that.

```html
<a *ngIf="userService.roleMatch !==  (['Admin'])" mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/homeb'" routerLinkActive="active">
  <i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home I miei dati
</a>
```

Comment: What is the type of `userService.roleMatch`?  you are comparing it with an array with a single value of `"Admin"`.  In JS, 2 arrays will not be equal unless they share the same reference in memory.

Comment: I assume userService.roleMatch is either an array or a function, for array, do ``userService.roleMatch.contains('Admin')`` or ``userService.roleMatch('Admin')`` if it's function

Comment: ' roleMatch(allowedRoles): boolean {
    var isMatch = false;
    var userRoles: string[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userRoles'));
    allowedRoles.forEach(element => {
      if (userRoles.indexOf(element) > -1) {
        isMatch = true;
        return false;
      }
    });
    return isMatch;
}'  @ wuiyang

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to make a class that will handle authorization.
And in it, make a function that will output everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
roleMatch(allowedRoles): boolean { 
    var isMatch = false; 
    var userRoles: string[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userRoles')); 
    for (let el of allowedRoles) {
      if (userRoles.indexOf(el) > -1) {
        isMatch = true;
        break;
      }
    } 
    return isMatch; 
  }

<a *ngIf="!userService.roleMatch(['Admin'])" mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/homeb'" routerLinkActive="active">
  <i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home I miei dati
</a>
```

Return false, inside foreach loop will not help i believe.